# Why does ElementFinder.find(...) no longer return a promise in Protractor 2.0?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

There is a [breaking change in protractor 2.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases/tag/2.0.0):

> - remove the `then` function from `element(by.foo)`

I'd like to know the rationale behind this change. Having ElementFinder.find return a promise is a pattern that we rely on heavily in our tests. I'm wondering if this is an anti-pattern for some reason.

I see that the commit this was changed in is [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/34f0eebd7e73b10e9b990caa06b63b6fd22b2589). The commit message describes what has changed, but not why it was done (other than to align itself more with Selenium webdriver, which just begs the question).

Comment: I believe Protractor was reacting to upstream changes from Webdriver that broke `then` handling on `Element` objects.  You can see a bit more discussion of the issue here (scroll down two the last three updates):  https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1872

Comment: Thanks, but begs the question as to why the change in Selenium.